# Need a workaround for sending email in Gmail via Microsoft email address

Tags: gmail, outlook.com, email-forwarding, smtp

I have has this issue for a while and its starting to cause problems so I need a workaround.

The problem is I use Gmail to send emails using my MSN account. When I send the email to multiple recipients which have different domains it sends the email to all recipients that many times. So if I send email to 3 recipients whose emails are jd@hotmail.com, jd@yahoo.com, jd@gmail.com, each user will get the same email 3 times. If I send the email to 3 recipients on the same domain it works as it should. When this issue happens, in Gmail only one email is being sent, but in outlook.com multiple emails show as sent.

[This forum post on Google](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/un1c47IpTpU/abk_AmzSAQAJ;context-place=topic/gmail/0PgC0zctJlI) shows the exact problem another user is having.

The result of that conversation is this quote:

> Microsoft are not following the guidelines set in RFC5321, so Google might choose not to implement a work around for Microsoft's behaviour even though Yahoo apparently has done that.

So my question is this: Is there any workaround for this issue? If not what other options do I have? I want to use Gmail/Inbox but my MSN email is on my business cards and has to be used as the From address.

I also have a GoDaddy email and I tried to set a identity for my MSN but it only works using the GoDaddy web interface. I was hoping it would work through Gmail using SMTP.

Is there another service out there to do what I need?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are using Gmail's option for [sending emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en), right?

Comment: That is correct.